# Save multiple fields from record in different collection in react-admin Form

Tags: react-admin

I'm using `react-admin` to manage a MongoDB database. A simplified example of the collections in the database:

```json
contacts = [
    { id: 8, name: "Joe", country: "UK" },
]

tasks = [
    { id: 0, description: "", dev: { contact_id: 8, name: "Joe" } },
]
```

The documents in `tasks` have to store both `contact_id` (contact doc reference) and `name` (shown in many different views, so the number of API calls can be reduced). In this case, I'd use an `AutocompleteInput` within a `ReferenceInput` to save `contact_id`.

```js
<ReferenceInput source="dev.contact_id" reference="contacts">
    <AutocompleteInput
        source="dev.contact_id"
        optionText="name"
        optionValue="id"
    />
</ReferenceInput>
```

However, once the contact is selected in the `Autocomplete`, I can't find a way to save the field `name`, so the `task` document looks like in the example. So far I've tried getting the `contact` record and adding the `name` field before submitting the form, but it's not working (hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component):

```js
export const TaskForm = ({ children }) => {
    const { handleSubmit } = useForm()

    const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        const contact = await useGetOne('contacts', { id: data?.dev?.contact_id })
        console.log(contact)
    }
    return (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            {children}
        </Form>
    )
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the dataProvider-hook instead of the useGetOne:

```
export const TaskForm = ({ children }) => {
    const { handleSubmit } = useForm()
    const dataProvider = useDataProvider();

    const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        const contact = await dataProvider.getOne('contacts', { id: data?.dev?.contact_id });
        console.log(contact)
    }
    return (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            {children}
        </Form>
    )
}
```